# how to pull href link

Tags: xpath

I am trying to pull a link from a page that is in a formal I can't seem to find by simply googling... it might be simple but xpath is not my area of expertise

I am using c# and trying to pull the link and just write it to the console to figure out how to get the link

here is my C# code

```
            var document = webGet.Load("http://classifieds.castanet.net/cat/vehicles/cars/0_-_4_years_old/");
        var browser = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[starts-with(@href,'/details/')]");
        if (browser != null)
        {
            string htmlbody = browser.OuterHtml;
           Console.WriteLine(htmlbody);

        }
```

the html code section is

```
<div class="last">&hellip;</div><a href="/cat/vehicles/cars/0_-_4_years_old/?p=13">13</a><a href="/cat/vehicles/cars/0_-_4_years_old/?p=2">&raquo;</a>
<select name="sortby" class="sortby" onchange="doSort(this);">
    <option value="">Most Recent</option>
    <option value="of" >Oldest First</option>
    <option value="mw" >Most Views</option>
    <option value="lw" >Fewest Views</option>
    <option value="lp" >Lowest Price</option>
    <option value="hp" >Highest Price</option>
</select><div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
                <a href="/details/2008_vw_gti/1454282/" class="prod_container" >
        <h2>2008 VW GTi</h2>
        <div style="float:left; width:122px; z-index:1000">
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://c.castanet.net/img/28/thumbs/1454282-1-1.jpg" border="0"/></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        mls
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
            The most fun car I have owned.  Dolphin Grey, 4 door, Dual Climate control, DRG Transmission with paddle shift.  Leather...
        </div>
        <div class="pdate">
            <p class="price">$19,000.00</p>
            <p class="date">Kelowna<br />Posted: Oct 15,  2:54 PM<br />Views: 349</p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both" ></div>
        <div class="seal"><img src="/images/bookmark.png" /></div>
        </a>
                <a href="/details/price_drop_gorgeous_rare_white_2009_honda_accord_ex-l_coupe/1447341/" class="prod_container" >
        <h2>PRICE DROP!!! Gorgeous Rare White 2009 Honda Accord EX-L Coupe </h2>
        <div style="float:left; width:122px; z-index:1000">
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://c.castanet.net/img/28/thumbs/1447341-1-1.jpg" border="0"/></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        sun2010
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
```

the link I'm trying to get is the "/details/2008_vw_gti/1454282/" part. THanks

Comment: I'm making a lot of assumptions here cause you only provide a small part of what the site may contain but try this: `//a[@class="prod_container"]/@href`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Xpath expression :

```
//a[@class="prod_container"]/@href
```

Comment: I have editied orginal post to add more details. The XPATH you provided just returned a blank in console

Comment: That works well, you can test it : `xmllint 2>/dev/null --html --xpath '//a[@class="prod_container"]/@href' http://stardust.hd.free.fr:8000` It's your code inside <body> tag...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML isn't XML**.
XPath is a tool for navigating through XML documents, however HTML does not conform to XML requirements. The HTML you've linked about isn't well formed XML, and as such XPath won't work.

You either need to look at using an HTML to XML convertor, and then adding the output of that conversion to your question to write XPath against, or investigate using a different tool for the job. I'd suggest doing a Google search for "C# HTML scrapers", but I'm not familiar with .Net so I can't offer a narrower option.